# Data Binding - Host properties exist without declaration

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am reviewing [polycasts ep 47 app code for blog-pages.html](https://github.com/Polymer/polycasts/blob/master/ep47-app-route-fouc/blog/elements/blog-pages.html), specifically the data binding.

In blog-pages.html, the host properties `isLoading`, `postsActive`, and `postsData` were not declared as `blog-pages` host properties. How was this possible since they are `blog-pages` host properties?

```
   <app-route route="{{route}}"
               pattern="/posts/:slug"
               active="{{postsActive}}"
               data="{{postsData}}"></app-route>

    <list-page category="{{category}}"
               active={{listActive}}
               loading="{{isLoading}}"></list-page>

    <post-page post="{{postsData.slug}}"
               active="{{postsActive}}"
               loading="{{isLoading}}"></post-page>

    <div class="overlay" hidden$="[[!isLoading]]">
      <paper-spinner active="[[isLoading]]"></paper-spinner>
    </div>

  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({

      is: 'blog-pages',

      observers: [
        '_lockScroll(isLoading)'
      ],

      _lockScroll: function(isLoading) {
        if (isLoading) {
          document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
        } else {
          document.body.style.overflow = 'visible';
        }
      }

    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not best example of how polymer works.. For beginners it might be confusing. All these variables you wrote are defined by some polymer's elements.

For example in `blog-app.html` you can see `app-route` which has property `data`, `tail` and `pattern`. When you look inside `app-route.html` file, you can see that property `tail` has `notify: true` option. Which means, that it will propagate this property to parent element. So when you define binding in app-route like: `<app-route tail="{{someProp}}"></app-route>` then in your element there will be existing `someProp` property.

The same is in other files. For example take a look at `isLoading`. In `blog-pages.html` you can see there is binding to `isLoading` but it is nowhere defined. Well it is. In child element. So open `list-page.html` and take a look at `<iron-ajax>` where you can see `loading="{{loading}}"`. And again the same. take a look inside `iron-ajax.html` and find property `loading`. What you see? again `notify: true` option. Which means, it get propagated to parent (`list-page.html`) and in `list-page.html` you can see there is also defined `loading` property which has `notify:true` so it gets propagated once more to parent (`blog-pages.html`)  And because in `blog-pages.html` we have binding `loading="{{isLoading}}"` then it's saved into `isLoading` property

And this is how polymer works.. This example of some project is really hard to udnerstand and for beginners it's impossible. I hope that my explanation helped you a little bit, but I think you are now much more confused :-D.

If you have more questions, then ask. It's no problem to explain something

Comment: I understand  the data binding completely and how it works, I've used it many of times - my question was NOT on how data binding works. 

My question is how this example correlates to documentation. There are *target* properties and *host* properties. In blog-pages, `isLoading` is a *host* property of blog-pages that was able to exist and be used **without declaring it in blog-pages**. Same with `postsActive`.

Comment: Better specify your question then. in your first sentence you ask about data-bindings. nevermind.......  i tried to read whole documentation about bindings.. yep some host attributes are really there. I think it might have something to do with plain javascript array and objects 'pointers' to memory.. But this is only discussion. I'll let others to answer your questions..  I have no idea why that downvote.

Comment: Reading some of Polymer 2.0 docs, they mentioned `implied` host properties from bindings. I think this might be a feature of Polymer 1.0 but not mentioned in the Polymer 1.0 docs. Thanks for trying to help.